# Invoke-Command create new object

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I've got a problem to create new object with `Invoke-Command`:

```
$a = 'TEST'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    param($a, $b, $c)
    $o = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    echo $a
} -ArgumentList ($a, $b, $c)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
La récupération de la fabrique de classes COM pour le composant avec le CLSID
{0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} a échoué en raison de l'erreur suivante :
80080005 Échec de l'exécution du serveur (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80080005
(CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-Object], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCOMClassIdentified,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

TEST
```

where the trailing "TEST" is the output of `echo $a`.

I can't create the new object remotly. can you help me?

Comment: Just in case, is Outlook installed and usable locally in PowerShell on that computer?

Comment: @wOxxOm  No. Outlook is not installed locally. Outlook is installed on the remote computer only.

Comment: Yes i can load this assembly and create new object locally on the $computer. but not remotely

Comment: No, you need to make sure it is installed correctly. So can you use it in PowerShell on that computer? Not remotely but by running the script in person, locally, on that computer?

Comment: Ok. thank you for answer. case closed.